# How to take a list of Objects and create a JSON of specific properties of the objects in the list?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[ Person({ getName: Function, id: '310394', age: 30 }), Person({ getName: Function, id: '244454', age: 31 })...]
```

and now I want to make it like this:

```
{
    peopleIds: [
         244454,244454...
  ]
}
```

I did something like this:

```
public makePeopleIdJSON(list: Person[]):void {
    list.forEach(x => console.log(x.id))
  }
```

that just prints the id for each object in the list, but how do I make the output a json as requested above..?

thanks allot

Comment: Do you mean `310394,244454...`? Otherwise I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is :

```
interface Person{
    id: string;
}
function makePeopleIdJSON(list: Person[]) {
    return {
        personIds: list.map(x => x.id)
    }
}
```